# paging for string.format in asp.net

Tags: for-loop, paging, string.format

I How to paging for string.format. I just like paging In Gridview.
For example, there are 20 100 records per page and the rest of the layout.

### preview   1 2 3 4 5   next

```
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("NewsContentMenu", cn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
        {
            using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    newsTabMenu.Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = string.Format("<a href='News.aspx?id={0}'>{1}</a></br>", dr["NewsID"], dr["NewsTitle"]) });
                }
            }
        }
```

### }

Dear friends, please help in this case. Grateful